# WPF ComboBox items (ItemsSource binding) are not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to bind `List<MyClass>` to `ComboBox`. Following is simple code which I implemented :

**C#**

```
cmbList.ItemsSource = DbMain.GetNameList();
```

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" >

    <TextBlock Text="Names:" Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbList" Width="200" SelectionChanged="cmbList_SelectionChanged"
      DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" SelectedValuePath="DisplayName" Foreground="Black"/>

</StackPanel>
```

**Problem**

Values of `List<MyClass>` are retrived from `DbMain.GetNameList()` and binding in `ComboBox` but those are not visible. When I perfrom `SelectionChanged`, I can access `SelectedItem` as well. Only issue is items are not visible.

[image]

**Error in Output Window**

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayName' property not found on 'object' ''MyClass' (HashCode=804189)'. BindingExpression:Path=DisplayName; DataItem='MyClass' (HashCode=804189); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

Comment: Check the output window, is there a binding error like 'cannot find property DisplayName'?

Comment: Are you providing the right DisplayMemberPath ? check for misspell

Comment: @kennyzx Yes. There is a error there.  `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayName' property not found on 'object' ''MyClass' (HashCode=804189)'. BindingExpression:Path=DisplayName; DataItem='MyClass' (HashCode=804189); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

Comment: Then that is classic binding error, you are expected to define a `DisplayName` property in `MyClass`.

Comment: I already defined it. I use this class at many other places and its working fine. Class definition `public class MyClass
{
    public int Id;
    public string DisplayName;
}` Is this due to no `get set` ?

Comment: Yes, make it a property with `getter` and/or `setter`, instead of a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using this binding expression, you are stating that there is a **property** named `DisplayName` in `MyClass`, but at runtime, since there is no such **property** - you define `DisplayName` as a **field**, that is why it fails in your case - so the `ComboBox` is showing blank items.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbList" 
  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
```

Unlike unhandled exceptions, this kind of binding errors don't crash the application, but you can find their trace in the output window while debugging.